# How to get Alexa to give sensor readings?

Tags: node-red

I'm trying to get my Alexa to take the readings from MQTT broker and tell me then when I ask her for the temperature. I can get her to read the readings that are set by me but when it comes from reading sensor and telling me the digits, it does not say anything.

This is my flow diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't just wire the MQTT input into the same flow as the HTTP request. MQTT provides asynchronous message delivery, you do not query it, it delivers messages when they are published, not on request.

You need to look at the documentation for storing values from MQTT messages in the [context](http://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#storing-data) and then retrieve that data with the HTTP request flow that handles the call from Alexa.